# tmux: open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: xterm-256color

Tags: terminal, tmux, terminfo

I used home-brew to setup tmux on a mac. When trying to run tmux I keep on getting this error

open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: xterm-256color

any suggestions?

Answer (score 56):

Your system doesn't have `xterm-256color`. You could:

- Set `TERM` to something other than `xterm-256color` outside `tmux` (try just plain `export TERM=xterm`).
- See if there is a package containing `xterm-256color`, perhaps a later version of ncurses or terminfo.
- Install it manually from another system with something like:

  ```
  infocmp -x xterm-256color > out
  ```

  Then transfer the "out" file to your Mac and try:

  ```
  tic out
  ```

Comment: `export TERM=xterm` Thanks it even works in OpenWRT whose 'tmux' has less functionalities.

Comment: infocmp & tic was what exactly what I was looking for (not even backspacing worked before that)

Answer (score 42):

This happened to me during a system upgrade. Unfortunately I did not see a way besides restarting: `tmux kill-server` and then run `tmux`.

Comment: Arch users: This is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Not just Arch.  Probably generically Linux.  And you don't have to kill your servers ungracefully.  In the shell, before you try to reattach, set TERM to some other value, such as `export TERM=xterm` or `export TERM=screen`, then you can reattach.  At that point, you can end all your programs and shells gracefully.  Once all the tmux sessions for the same user are ended, you can restart tmux with the new version.

Comment: Not even generically Linux. I had to do this after updating MacPorts while tmux was running. Fortunately I saw this before trying more radical solutions.

Comment: I didn't want to kill tmux, because then I would have no way to interact with the upgrade. `export TERM=xterm` was the solution.

Answer (score 25):

you can just type `export TERM=xterm` in console when you see this error, or put `export TERM=xterm` in the file `~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.bash_profile`. then you may never get this error again.
This works fine on my debian.

Comment: This also worked on Windows. On [tmux with git bash](https://gist.github.com/DeanPDX/acff533cff0cfbda2761d1e62e8cb1a7).

Answer (score 20):

## TL;DL

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-color /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
```

## Details

Maybe the file `/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color` is corrupted. It may be fixed upon (system/package) upgrade / reinstall.

Meanwhile you can use other terminfo entry. You can get the available options by `ls /usr/share/terminfo/x`.

I am having the same problem and using `xterm-16color` meanwhile.

To set terminfo, you can type `reset` in the terminal, then select the terminfo:

```
username:~$ cd /usr/share/terminfo/x
username:x$ ls
x10term          xnuppc+200x64    xterm-24         xterm+pcfkeys
x1700            xnuppc-200x64-m  xterm-256color   xterm-pcolor
x1700-lm         xnuppc-200x75    xterm+256color   xterm-r5
...
username:x$ reset
reset: unknown terminal type xterm-256color
Terminal type? xterm-16color
```

=== Edit 2018 Feb 20 ===

You should config the term in many places if you want to make it permanent, for example, .vimrc, .tmux.config, .Xresources, e.t.c.

I still have issue when using `terminator -x 'tmux attach -t music; exec bash'`
So I'm using a quick hack as below:

```
cd /usr/share/terminfo/x
sudo mv xterm-256color xterm-256color.bk
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-color /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 10):

When I removed some sessions/windows this error went away for me. Apparently I had too many TTY's open.

You can kill sessions/windows from outside tmux with these commands:

```
tmux kill-session -t <session-name>
tmux kill-window -t <session-name>:<window-name>
```

Answer (score 5):

I am also having the same issue.

```
export TERM=xterm
tmux kill-server
```

This helps solve the problem: https://www.peterdavehello.org/2019/11/tmux-open-terminal-failed-missing-or-unsuitable-terminal-xterm-256color/

Answer (score 0):

In my case Xterm was absent. 
(But I had the same error on Ubuntu)